# Div and video, different heights for 100%

Tags: html, css

I've got a `<video>` inside a `<div>` and the height for `<video>` is set to be 100%. The video's height on page is 759px and the div gets to 764px. There's no padding/margin set, so how do I end up with those 5px more for div?

css for div

```
.wrapper {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92);
}
```

css for video

```
 <video  width="100%" height="100%" poster="poster.jpg" 
                    preload="auto"  autoplay style="visibility: visible; width: 100%; height:100%;border: 0;"  
                    src="test.mp4">
                    <source type="video/mp4" src="test.mp4" >                   
                    </video>
```

computed css for video:

```
border-bottom-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
display: inline-block;
font-family: Raleway, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 759px;
line-height: 20px;
object-fit: contain;
visibility: visible;
width: 1349px;
```

computed for div

```
Show inherited properties
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.921569);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
display: block;
font-family: Raleway, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 764px;
line-height: 20px;
width: 1349px;
```

Comment: Please give us more CSS Code. 
And please make sure to have a look at the `border-size` of your `<video>` tag. So set `border: 0;` if you dont need it.

Comment: Is the video actually 759 pixels high? Most videos need to have dimensions a multiple of 4 pixels